# Не срабатывает break в JS коде

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express

Есть код проверки существования юзера, который выполняется но, если юзер существует он должен выдать  в консоль "юзер существует" и остановить программу.

Вместо этого, программа выполняется и в JSON записывается новый юзер (создается дубль) причем создается **три записи**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот сам код:

```
app.use("/register", function (request, response) {
    console.log(request.body);

    fs.readFile("./data/users/users.json", "utf-8", function (err, text) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("ERROR READING FILE" + err);
        } else {
            var users = JSON.parse(text);

            for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {

                if (users[i].email === request.body.email) {

                    console.log("user already exists");
                    break;

                } else {

                    users.push(request.body);
                    fs.writeFile("./data/users/users.json", JSON.stringify(users), function () { // write new user to json

                    });
                }
            }
        }


    });
});
```

Может у кого-то есть пример регистрационной / авторизационной формы с проверками на Angular & Express?

Comment: Вы же сами написали добавление новой записи в цикле! Вот она и добавляется несколько раз.

Comment: что должен сделать твой алгоритм, если `request.body.email` совпадает не с `users[0].email`, а с `users[1].email`?

Comment: а почему не использовать `return;` ?

Comment: @Insider, потому что, если совпадение будет со вторым элементом, а не с первым, на первой итерации цикла этот пользователь спокойно добавится

Comment: виноват, исправлюсь. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы добавляете пользователя, до тех пор пока не встретится совпадение в файле. От этого и дублирование.

Необходимо проверять наличие и или отсутствие пользователя, и уже на основе этого делать решение о записи:

```
var user_in_db = false;
for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
  if (users[i].email === request.body.email) {
    console.log("user already exists");
    user_in_db = true;
    break;
  }
}

if(!user_in_db){
  users.push(request.body);
  fs.writeFile("./data/users/users.json", 
    JSON.stringify(users), 
    function () { 
     /*write new user to json*/ 
    });
}
```